# Asynctask is still blocking the main thread in Android app

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am trying to update the application's SQLite Database with the one stored on [Parse](http://www.parse.com)

I am calling the function to update the database in Asynctask but it is still blocking the main thread as my application hangs and shows "Not responding" error when the function is executed.

Here is my code, it is written in onCreate() in an Activity.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB){

        new SaveCourses().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, mDbHelper);
            }
            else {
                new SaveCourses().execute(mDbHelper);

            }
```

SaveCourses class is written in the end of the Activity class,

```
class SaveCourses extends AsyncTask<Object, Integer, Object> {
    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object... ctx) {
    System.out.println("in background method - async");
    ((TestAdapter) ctx[0]).SaveCourses_1();
    return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Object... mDbHelper) {
        ((TestAdapter) mDbHelper[0]).close();   
    }
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values)
    {

    }

}
```

Could any of you please guide me as to what is the problem with my code.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You sure it isn't crashing? You `return null` in `doInBackground()` then in `onPostExecute()` it should crash with an NPE since `mDbHelper` (the parameter) is null.

Comment: no it is not crashing because mDbHelper is not NULL, I am creating and initializing it as follows,

Comment: TestAdapter mDbHelper = new TestAdapter(getBaseContext());         
     mDbHelper.createDatabase();       
     mDbHelper.open();

Comment: You're variable shadowing, you do realize? Not to mention that `onPostExecute()`'s `mDbHelper` is an array of `TestAdapters`, not just one `TestAdapter` Try instead of `return null`, `return ctx [0]` and modify `onPostExecute()` so it doesn't accept varargs, it's not supposed to. `onPostExecute(Object mDbHelper) { is what it should be` Then, you also don't need `mDbHelper[0]` you can change it to `mDbHelper`

Comment: I modified the code as per your comments, but it is still behaving the same. The main thread is blocked and the UI is hanged.

Comment: In that case I'm not sure, LogCat *may* say something.

Comment: There are no error messages in Logcat.

Comment: Are you sure this code is where it is hanging?  Where are you actually downloading the data?  In `onCreate`?  It could be hanging there. As at @A--C pointed out, your program should have crashed because of the variable shadow in `onPostExecute`, so your ANR is probably coming before that routine gets a chance to run.

Comment: I am calling,                                                       new SaveCourses().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, mDbHelper);                                                            in onCreate of Activity. The doInBackground method in Asynctask class will be calling another method to update the application's database. So, when this method starts executing, it is simply blocking the main UI. I tried removing all the code from onPostExecute as well, it is still behaving the same.